# Fix git branching issue

Tags: git, gitlab

I am uncertain how to fix this one and feel like I may have painted myself into a corner.

[image: git log graphed]

Above is my git tree graphed and all the relevant branches. As you can see, I've somehow left master behind. The reason for this is that master contains some broken code somewhere in those 4 commits.

I would like to abandon that entire branch and stick master on the same level at T156 and if possible maybe merge one commit from the T145-Fix-app-php branch into the now T156 branch.

BTW I do most of my commits using standard git commands at the CLI and the screen shot was taken from the latest version of gitlabs. So either tool is available for me to fix this SNAFU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay with *discarding* your existing `master` branch, then maybe:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard T156
```

If you want to preserve the old `master` branch, then maybe:

```
git checkout master
git branch old-master
git reset --hard T156
```

This preserve your old `master` branch as `old-master`.

Comment: Also, remember that if you want to experiment on your repository without fear of screwing things up, just make a copy of it and work on that until you're happy.